How to protect NextJS's Route Handlers from being accessed outside my website
I'm using NextJS 14 App Router, and I have multiple Route Handlers for my APIs, but I was surprised to know that my friend was able to send requests to my Route Handlers using Postman from his PC.
I thought that by default they were protected because the headers in NextJS are following a same-origin policy.
But apparently, CORS (Cross-Origin Resource Sharing) and SOP (Same-Origin Policy) are server-side configurations that clients decide to enforce or not. And Postman does not enforce them.
So, Is there a way to prevent my Route Handlers from being accessed from outside my website?
This is my code.


  
// Client component || Form.tsx

  async function sendText(text: string) {
    
        const translateResponse = await fetch("/api/translate-text", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          text: text,
        }),
      });

      const translatedData = await translateResponse.json();

}





   
   //  api/translate-text/route.ts

export async function POST(request: Request) {
  const { text} = await request.json();

  const res = await fetch(
    `https://api-source.com`,
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Key": process.envAPI_KEY || "",
        "Host": process.env.API_HOST || "",
      },
      body: new URLSearchParams({
        from: "auto",
        to: "en",
        text: text,
      }),
    }
  );

  const translatedText = await res.json();
  return NextResponse.json(translatedText, {
    status: 201,
  });
}




Make sure you're using the use-client and use-server headers in your files
This ensures they are running in the right place
https://nextjs.org/docs/app/building-your-application/rendering/server-components

It's not that.
I'm using "use client" in the Form.tsx component

can you post your directory structure? Since in nextJS the directory impacts routes. You can run tree -I node_modules if on linux based systems

Also -- ensure you have use-server in the ones you do not want accessible in the client

I apologize for the delayed response, but the company's priorities have shifted. You can access my folder structure from this link. As for the use of the use-server keyword, I don't think it's the issue, as this keyword is reserved for server actions, and I'm not using any in my project.
